# When using script for WinSCP it opens another folder

Tags: bash, script, automation, sftp

I am trying to automate process of downloading files from SFTP server using WinSCP.

But I am having issues with the execution of one part of the code.
When the connection is established instead getting to the specified directory it is changing in a directory, which I never mentioned in the script.

What could be the problem and if anyone could help with solution?

In continuation are the error message, and scripts. Some parts with passwords and usernames are covered but correct. I manually connect with them.

Output

```
batch           abort
confirm         off
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Using username "bancaintesa".
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Authenticated.
Starting the session...
Session started.
Error changing directory to 'C:\Users\darkovuj\Desktop'.
System Error.  Code: 2.
The system cannot find the file specified
Active session: [1] **********@195.178.44.158
0 File(s) copied
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Script from .bat file

```
@echo off
setlocal

REM === Starting SFTP Download Task ===
echo Starting SFTP Download Task

REM Set your SFTP server credentials
set SFTP_USER=********
set SFTP_PASS=*********
set SFTP_SERVER=195.178.44.158
set SFTP_PORT=22

REM Set the local folder paths
set DESTINATION_DIR=C:\olconnect\BI_SNE\input

echo getting date

REM Get the current date in YYYYMMDD format
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (
    set "YYYY=%%c"
    set "MM=%%a"
    set "DD=%%b"
)
set CURRENT_DATE=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%

echo date completed

REM Create the download directory with the current date
set DOWNLOAD_DIR=C:\olconnect\BI_SNE\backup\%CURRENT_DATE%
mkdir "%DOWNLOAD_DIR%"

REM Specify the path to the WinSCP commands file
set WINSCP_SCRIPT_PATH=C:\olconnect\BI_SNE\download_automation.txt

REM Run WinSCP to download files and delete them from the server
"C:\winscp514\winscp.com" /script="%WINSCP_SCRIPT_PATH%"


REM Copy downloaded files to the destination directory
xcopy /Y /I "%DOWNLOAD_DIR%\*.pdf" "%DESTINATION_DIR%"

echo completed copying...

REM Keep the window open to see the output
pause

endlocal
```

And code for WinSCP commands txt

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://%SFTP_USER%:%SFTP_PASS%@%SFTP_SERVER%:%SFTP_PORT% -hostkey="ssh-ed25519 255 *************************"
cd /SNETest
lcd %DOWNLOAD_DIR%
get *.pdf
rm *.pdf
exit
```

It would be great if someone could help!!!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Error changing directory to 'C:\Users\darkovuj\Desktop'.
```

This path comes somewhere from your GUI or profile settings. The error appears even before WinSCP tries to change the remote directory so does not reach this part of the script:

```
cd /SNETest
lcd %DOWNLOAD_DIR%
```

The option `/ini=nul` should fix it:

```
"C:\winscp514\winscp.com" /ini=nul /script="%WINSCP_SCRIPT_PATH%"
```

But this also will disable/change other currently active settings. So be aware to check and provide the required details for this session.

---

You also could store the details for the session in an ini-file so making the batch- and script-parts of your project simpler.

In this case call:

```
"C:\winscp514\winscp.com" /ini="MyConfig.ini" /script="%WINSCP_SCRIPT_PATH%"
```

Comment: +1 – See also https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#configuration

Comment: Thank you on your quick reply and it was very helpful it works!!!

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should set the "answered" hook.